# Python/Scrapy Go to a different URL

Tags: python, scrapy

So I am working on a small project with scrapy and I am kinda new to python and scrapy.

I am trying to scrap information about every firm on this URL.https://www.canadianlawlist.com

I create a form request and get results : https://www.canadianlawlist.com/searchresult/?searchtype=firms&city=Montreal

Now I want for each results to scrap the basic data like Name/Phone etc.

But the link changes to something completly else.

Something like https://www.canadianlawlist.com/listingdetail/company/zsa-legal-recruitment-673544/ .

I tried having a basic url : canadianlawlist.com and then appending the href like that :

```
basicurl = "canadianlawlist.com/"
    products = response.xpath('//*[@class="searchresult_item_regular"]/a/@href').extract()
    for p in products:
        url = urljoin(response.url, p)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_firm_info)
```

but I am using python 2 and I can use urljoin(I think)?

Any ideas how I can proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy have `response.urljoin()` for this task:

```
products = response.xpath('//*[@class="searchresult_item_regular"]/a/@href').extract()
for p in products:
    url = response.urljoin(p)
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_firm_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Scrapy version >= 1.4, there is pretty handy `response.follow` method described here:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.follow

Moreover Scrapy has more effective mechanism to extract links called `LinkExtractor` https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html It accepts not only xpaths but css selectors and extracts all the nested links for them (and have many more handy features).

Combining both of above your Spider could look like:

```
class TheSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'the_spider'
    start_urls = [...]
    links_extractor = LinkExtractor(restrict_css='.searchresult_item_regular')

def parse(self, response):
    for l in self.links_extractor.extract_links(response):
        yield response.follow(l, self.parse_firm_info)
```

Or using `CrawlSpider` https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider it could be even more elegant:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class TheSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'the_spider'
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='.searchresult_item_regular'), callback='parse_firm_info'),
    )
    start_urls = [...]

    def parse_firm_info(self, response):
        ...
```